Whisper transcribes Ukrainian speech, but writes it in Latin characters. How to fix it?
I wrote the code for transcription of Ukrainian speech, the Whisper transcribes, but saves the file written in Latin characters. I also tried it without setting language to Ukrainian.
model = whisper.load_model("base")
option = whisper.DecodingOptions(language="ua")
result = model.transcribe("C:/Users/1/Documents/Python/transcription/test.mp3", fp16=False)
file = open("transcription_1.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(result["text"])
file.close()

